# Dojo BorderContainer wrong size after changing from display:none to display:block

Tags: layout, dojo

I'm using dojo layout with splitters. Inside the layout with splitters there is a bordercontainer-div (inside a contentPane), which has some splitters on its own. This one is set to display:none during runtime. After setting it to display:block again it has its old size and not the actual size of the surrounding div, which it should have. Just after resizing the surrounding div it suddenly jumps to the size it should have. Can I somehow force the resizing process? I already tried: dijit.byId("BorderContainer").resize() but this doesn't help.

Would be great if someone has an idea!

Best regards and thanks,
Sezunna

Comment: you have to call the resize command of the parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try "display:inline" rather than "display:block" for all containers in Dojo. Else, you need to do all the re-sizing and formatting again.